# how to iterate through a list inside a series

Tags: python, pandas, list, nlp, series

I have a `series` that contains a `list` inside. Each `list` in the `series` has a different length. The reason is because I had a `string` originally inside the `series`, and then I applied the `nltk` `word_tokenize()` function.

I have tried using `apply() lambda` functions but have been unsuccessful.
For example, to count the frequency of unique words I tried:

```
summary_word_frequency = df.summary_word_tokens.apply(lambda x: [x.value_counts() for x in df.summary_word_tokens])
```

Some insights on my data and how it is structured:

In:

```
print(type(df.summary_word_tokens))
print(type(df.summary_word_tokens[0]))
print(type(df.summary_word_tokens[0][1]))
```

Out:

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'str'>
```

In:

```
print(df.summary_word_tokens.shape)
print(df.summary_word_tokens[0])
print(df.summary_word_tokens[0][1])
```

Out:

```
(1000,)
['cake', 'type', 'is', 'cake', 'chocolate']
type
```

My goal is to be able to iterate through all the rows, as I want to be able to feed the tokens into an algorithm.

Or would you all recommend a different way to tokenize/ making the list into a series (so it'd be a series within a series)? And does it matter the way you tokenize if the problem is unsupervised?

Thanks

Comment: Provide any sample of your `I/P` data please!

Comment: @hygull have updated my post :)